# On the command line, 'find' reports back an illegal time value

Tags: linux, find, date, csh

I want to run the following command.

find . -mtime -60s

When I do, I get this output instead:

```
CLIENT% echo `date +%s`-1308741881 | bc
5152
CLIENT% find . -mtime -`echo `date +%s`-1308741881 | bc`s
-1308741881: Command not found.
find: -mtime: -date: illegal time value
CLIENT%
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that ` marks are used to denote commands who's output should be substituted in your command...  so your command is actually three commands:

1. "echo " (contained in the first set of 1 marks)
2. "-1308741881 | bc" (contained in the second set of 1 marks)
3. find . -mtime -**OUTPUT FROM COMMAND #1**date +%s**OUTPUT FROM COMMAND #2**

Command #1 outputs nothing, and command #2 results in the "Command not found" error, because **-1308741881** is not a valid command, then outputs nothing either.

Then finally the third command runs, with those replacements and looks like this:

```
find . -mtime -date
```

And since "-date" isn't a valid time, it complains about that, too, saying "illegal time value"

The underlying problem is that you're trying to use nested `` marks, which the shell interprets as two separate commands.

A better way to express what you want is this (for bash):

```
find . -mtime -$(echo $(date +%s-1308741881) | bc)s
```

And for csh:

```
set now=`date +%s-1308741881`; set date=`echo $now | bc`s; find . -mtime -$date
```

And possibly for other shells (untested):

```
NOW=`date +%s-1308741881`; DATE=`echo $NOW | bc`; find . -mtime -${DATE}s
```

---

P.S. I don't think this does what you expect... your date command is returning a number of seconds, but -mtime expects a number of days as input. I'm guessing you'll probably want to adjust your date command accordingly.

Comment: CLIENT% find . -mtime -$(echo $(date +%s-1308741881 ) | bc )s
Illegal variable name.

Comment: Which shell are you using? Maybe it doesn't understand $() syntax

Comment: I've updated my answer with another version of the same command that might work better in other shells.  Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I am using csh shell.

Comment: Okay, I have appended my answer once again, with a command that I have tested to work with csh.  However, note that find does not accept 'seconds' as a valid -mtime paramater (at least not with my version of find), so the command still fails in that regard.